# Match two rows value cell by cell till last used cell

Tags: vba, excel

**Case 1**
Match the two rows cell value one by one till last used cell in same row. Rows are last row is sheet 1 and second last row. There is one blank row between last row and second to last row. There are some blank cells in both rows and data start from column "D".

**Case 2**
If cells match then go in next cell in same row or if cell value not match change the background colour of second last row cell of that particular column which value is not match.

Once all mapping is done delete the last row.

My code that is not working:

```
Sub copyRow()
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

'ws = ActiveWorkbook("sheet1").Select

Set rng = ws.Range("A6").End(xlUp).Offset(-2, 0).Select
lRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


Set MR = Range("A2:A" & lRow)
For Each cell In MR
    If cell.Value = "False" Then
    rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 10
      ElseIf cell.Value = "True" Then
End If


Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This question looks like a request for code-writing service, i.e. a bit inappropriate for SO. Please bring us your VBA code snippet and highlight the problematic part. You can use a Macro Recorder to create a quick proto, then polish your code. Best regards,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's looks like home work problem.

Comment: please edit the question so we can actually read the code...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow (SO). Please refer to [this link for how to ask a question here in SO.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) When 5 close votes are cast by the community, your question will be closed. Make sure to specify where exactly you are getting an error in your code, what help you need from the community in terms of solving this programming problem/bottle neck.